# Image button in included layout wont fire onclicklistener on ActionDown

Tags: android, onclicklistener

Here is code:
It is a menu that is included to almost every page and I want to navigate throw pages with this menu but onClicks wont fire i tried onTouch action down and everything nothing works . Please help thanks.

```
public class BottomNavBar extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bottom_nav_bar);
    ImageButton schedule = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btmSchedule);
    ImageButton map = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btmMap);
    final ImageButton liveFeed = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btmLivefeed);
    ImageButton message = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btmMessage);
    ImageButton profile = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btmProfile);
    schedule.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScheduleActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            if ((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)) {

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    liveFeed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(BottomNavBar.this, "startedLiveFeed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LiveFeedActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),UserProfile.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    schedule.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ScheduleActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    message.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NewsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    map.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),VideosActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}
```

xml parent

```
   <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="false">
<include layout="@layout/content_nav_bar" />
```

parent content

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_weight="5"
android:id="@+id/content_navbar"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="false">
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/btmSchedule"
    android:src="@drawable/schedule"
    android:background="#F0F4F7"
    android:layout_gravity="center|left"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/asd" />
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/map"
    android:id="@+id/btmMap"
    android:background="#F0F4F7"
    android:layout_gravity="center|left"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/asd" />
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/livefeed"
    android:id="@+id/btmLivefeed"
    android:background="#F0F4F7"
    android:layout_gravity="center|left"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/asd"
    android:padding="5dp"/>
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/message"
    android:id="@+id/btmMessage"
    android:background="#F0F4F7"
    android:layout_gravity="center|left"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/asd" />
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/profile"
    android:id="@+id/btmProfile"
    android:background="#F0F4F7"
    android:layout_gravity="center|left"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/asd" />
```

Comment: did you tried with onClickListener() ??

Comment: Maybe try to remove the android:focusable="false" in both linearLayout and the clickable= true also

Comment: @Vivek yes no luck @ chol thanks for advice but no still does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class FasTestFragment extends UtuBaseFragment implements
        View.OnClickListener {

    @Bind(R.id.btmSchedule)
    ImageButton btmSchedule;
    @Bind(R.id.btmMap)
    ImageButton btmMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_include, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        btmSchedule.setOnClickListener(this);
        btmMap.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        int id = v.getId();
        if (id == R.id.btmSchedule) {
            System.out.println("****Schedule clicked.");
        }else if (id == R.id.btmMap) {
            System.out.println("****map clicked.");
        }
    } 
}
```

//test.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:id="@+id/content_navbar"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/btmSchedule"
        android:src="@drawable/fas_void"
        android:background="#F0F4F7"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="123" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/fas_user"
        android:id="@+id/btmMap"
        android:background="#F0F4F7"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="123" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/fas_enquiry"
        android:id="@+id/btmLivefeed"
        android:background="#F0F4F7"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="123"
        android:padding="5dp"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/fas_payment"
        android:id="@+id/btmMessage"
        android:background="#F0F4F7"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="123" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/fas_summary"
        android:id="@+id/btmProfile"
        android:background="#F0F4F7"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="123" />

</LinearLayout>
```

//test_include.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false">
    <include layout="@layout/test" />

</LinearLayout>
```

//Result

```
07-27 11:51:51.641 492-492/com.UTU I/System.out: ****Schedule clicked.
07-27 11:51:51.761 492-492/com.UTU D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
07-27 11:51:51.831 492-492/com.UTU D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
07-27 11:51:51.831 492-492/com.UTU I/System.out: ****Schedule clicked.
07-27 11:51:53.271 492-492/com.UTU D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
07-27 11:51:53.351 492-492/com.UTU D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
07-27 11:51:53.351 492-492/com.UTU I/System.out: ****map clicked.
07-27 11:51:53.461 492-492/com.UTU D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
07-27 11:51:53.531 492-492/com.UTU D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
07-27 11:51:53.531 492-492/com.UTU I/System.out: ****map clicked.
07-27 11:51:53.641 492-492/com.UTU D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
07-27 11:51:53.711 492-492/com.UTU D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
07-27 11:51:53.721 492-492/com.UTU I/System.out: ****map clicked.
07-27 11:51:53.841 492-492/com.UTU D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
07-27 11:51:53.901 492-492/com.UTU D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
07-27 11:51:53.901 492-492/com.UTU I/System.out: ****map clicked.
07-27 11:51:54.031 492-492/com.UTU D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
07-27 11:51:54.101 492-492/com.UTU D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
07-27 11:51:54.101 492-492/com.UTU I/System.out: ****map clicked.
07-27 11:51:54.211 492-492/com.UTU D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
07-27 11:51:54.271 492-492/com.UTU D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
07-27 11:51:54.271 492-492/com.UTU I/System.out: ****map clicked.
```